# How to select only one polyline at a time on map

Tags: android

i have tried many ways but couldn't find any thing related to this.i can show multiple paths between two locations like.

[image]

but when i click on polyline i have changed selected polylines color and it works fine. but because there are multiple routes are overlaping i can not manage to show that polyline at top of all other.

[image]

and when i click on another polyline second time that polyline also changes the color but previously selected polyline that should be change its color.

[image]

so help me out how should i handle this...

thank you.

**onDirectionFinderSuccess**

```
 @Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(final List<Route> routes)
{
    commonUtils.hideProgressDialog();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++)
    {
        Route route = routes.get(i);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 13));

        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_dot))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));
        destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_dot))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));


        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.GRAY).clickable(true).
                width(7);

        for (int j = 0; j < route.points.size(); j++)
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(j));
        routepoints = route.points.toString();

        polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

        mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
            {
                polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here i am listing general Logic for Select Polyline from multiple polyline**

First store all polyline in `polylines`

```
 private List<Polyline> polylines = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add your all polyline into polylines  for future use using below code

```
 Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .addAll(list)
                            .width(15)
                            .color(colorCode).geodesic(true));
                    polyline.setClickable(true);
  polylines.add(polyline);
```

set default polyline as selected and Update the polyline when polyline is clicked

```
setSelectedPath(polylines.get(0).getId());
  mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                       
                        //update the poliline as selected 
                        setSelectedPath(polyline.getId());
                    }
                });
```

Function for update the polyline as selected and unselect other polyline

```
 void setSelectedPath(String id) {

        Polyline selectedPolyLine = null;
       for (int i = 0; i < polylines.size(); i++) {
            Polyline polyline = polylines.get(i);
            polyline.setZIndex(0);
            if (polyline.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                selectedPolyLine = polyline;
                selectedPolyLine.setZIndex(10);
            }
            
            // set unselected color to poliline
            polyline.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(Color.GRAY);
        }


        if (selectedPolyLine != null) {
            // set selected color to polyline
            selectedPolyLine.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }       
    }
```

**Note**:  **selectedPolyLine.setZIndex(10);** is needed because it get your polyline on TOP from other polyline and display the set color properly without any overlapping.

In Your case
you have to call setSelectedPath() with polyline id from `onPolylineClick`

Answer (score 1):

1. To show the selected polyline over the others, you have to set the zIndex.
2. To deselect the previously selected line, you must save the polyline into a global variable

   ```
   public Polyline pathToTraverse;

   @Override
   public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(final List<Route> routes)
   {
       ...

       mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new     GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
           {

               if(pathToTraverse != null)
                   pathToTraverse.setColor(Color.GRAY);
               pathToTraverse = polyline;
               polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
               polyline.setZIndex(routes.size() - 1);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Subrata. not it selecting only one polyline at a time but still some polyline overlapping on selected polyline.

Comment: Try manipulating with the zIndex. It will work. Setting `setZIndex(routes.size())` maybe.

Comment: no i have tried this option but no any change it changed when i setzIndex(10)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the color of all your polylinePaths routes to Gray...

and then set click listener..

```
 mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline)
            {
                polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });
```